# Search only working on front page (index) , not working on other pages

Tags: php

I am using a wordpress theme and I've run into a problem with the search box.
When I use the searchbox from the homepage, it works as intended.(url.com/?s=1#)

But, when I use the searchbox from another page, the URL looks something like this: http://url.com/pretty-page-title/?s=1#   and a 404 page appears.

My search box code looks like this:

```
<?php
get_header();
```

?>

```
<section class="main-content-area-wrap">
    <div class="search-page-wrap">
        <div class="search-page-s1 layout-tweak">
            <div class="gc-container">
                <?php gucherry_blog_breadcrumb(); ?>
                <div id="primary" class="content-area">
                    <main class="site-main">
                        <div class="search-inner">
                            <div class="row">
                               <?php 
                                $sidebar_position = get_theme_mod( 'gucherry_blog_site_pages_search_page_sidebar_position', 'right' );
                                if( $sidebar_position == 'left' && is_active_sidebar( 'gucherry-blog-sidebar' ) ) {
                                    get_sidebar();
                                }
                                ?>
                                <div class="<?php gucherry_blog_main_container_class(); ?>">
                                    <div class="search-entry">
                                        <div class="page-title">
                                            <h1>
                                                <?php
                                                /* translators: %s: search query. */
                                                printf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s', 'gucherry-blog' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' );
                                                ?>
                                            </h1>
                                        </div><!-- // page-ttile -->
                                        <div class="search-items-entry">
                                          <?php
                                           if( have_posts() ) :
                                            ?>
                                            <div class="gc-blog-lists gc-blog-list-s1">
                                                <?php
                                
                                                /* Start the Loop */
                                                    while ( have_posts() ) :

                                                        the_post();

                                                        /*
                                                         * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                                                         * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                                                         * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                                                         */

                                                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

                                                    endwhile;
                                                
                                                    gucherry_blog_pagination();
                                                ?>   
                                            </div><!-- // gc-blog-lists gc-blog-list-s1 -->
                                            <?php

                                            else :

                                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
                                            endif;
                                            ?>
                                        </div><!-- // search-items-entry -->
                                    </div><!-- // search-entry -->
                                </div><!-- // col -->
                                <?php
                                if( $sidebar_position == 'right' && is_active_sidebar( 'gucherry-blog-sidebar' ) ) {
                                    get_sidebar();
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div><!-- // row -->
                        </div><!-- // search-inner -->
                    </main><!-- // site-main -->
                </div><!-- // # primary -->
            </div><!-- // gc-container -->
        </div><!-- // search-page-s1 layout-tweak -->
    </div><!-- // search-page-wrap -->
</section><!-- // main-content-area-wrap -->
```

Comment: Are you using a search plugin, the default Wordpress search or perhaps 'gucherry' have their own search plugin? Either way - The code you've posted here has no relevance to your question as it does not show how your search plugin/coding is constructing the URL's.

Comment: _"My search box code looks like this:"_ - and which part of that actually creates the search form? It sounds like the `action` for that might simply not be set correctly, to target the root URL.

Comment: I am not using any plugin. That's the problem with the theme called Gucherry itself.